Incorrect return type allowed for forward declared function: Why is there no linker error here?
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

a.cc
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

static int x = 5053;

void f2();

int main() {
  cout << "a: " << x << endl;
  f2();
  return 0;
}

b.cc
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

static int x = 4921;

string f2() {
  cout << "b: " << x << endl;
  return "";
}

Output
$ g++ --std=c++17 a.cc b.cc && ./a.out
a: 5053
b: 4921

Why was I able to forward declare string f2(); from b.cc as void f2(); in a.cc?
Any references to cppreference or spec that allows this would be appreciated.

try doing extern void f2();

Turn on all warnings. What's probably happening is it is calling the first available match, which happens to be string f2 because void f2 is not defined.

g++ --std=c++17 a.cpp b.cpp && ./a.out /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZVfIKp.o: in function main':
a.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to f2()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
This is what I got

@kesarlingHe-Him 
cat a.cc | grep extern <br> extern void f2();.
g++ -Wall --std=c++17 a.cc b.cc && ./a.out <br> a: 5053 b: 4921

What do you think cat a.cc | grep extern extern void f2(); does?

Program doesn't work here. We get a linker error.

@kesarlingHe-Him Functions are already extern. No need to write extern void f2();

@user12002570, I sure hope you aren't saying that string f2 is an overload of void f2.

@user12002570 if that is so, then please explain this

@kesarlingHe-Him We should indeed get a linker error as shown in the demo. Still note that you can omit writing extern here with f2

@kesarlingHe-Him Was just trying to show that adding extern didn't lead to any warnigns/errors with g++ -Wall for me. However, on an unrelated note, with -Weverything, regardless of having extern in the forward declaration in a.cc, I get -Wmissing-prototypes, i.e. b.cc:7:8: warning: no previous prototype for function 'f2' [-Wmissing-prototypes] .

@ps_ Both gcc and clang produce linker error. Demo

@ps_, there you go! I think this has got something to do with the OS. Some OSs add non-standard features leading to horrible coding practices (remember int a[n]; or #include <bits/stdc++.h>?)

@user12002570 "We should indeed get a linker error" No we should not. We might be so lucky that sometimes, in very special circumstances, we get a linker error.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, I am aware that it is not a bug. For some reason, I forgot that here a diagnostic is not required. I've updated the answer to reflect the same. Thanks for reminding me to remove the "it is a bug" part.

We don't always get a linker error because the C++ standard does not require a linker error or any other error in this case, and the implementations most of the time do not go the extra mile.
The standard does not require an error because the common linker technology does not allow the implementation to detect such errors.
Stroustrup decided to leave the return type out of C++ name mangling, so that names of two functions that differ only by their return type mangle to the same symbol name. This makes some ODR violation errors silently go undetected. Making the return type participate in the mangling would make other ODR violation errors go undetected.
There is no way to make all ODR-violation errors detectable with existing commonly available linkers. So the standard essentially permits the implementation to do what the original Stroustrup's compiler did: leave the return type out of the name mangling.
The compiler you use does just that. So it is something like _Z2f2v in the object file. You can see that by typing nm a.o | grep f2 and nm b.o | grep f2, or looking at the assembly output on the compiler explorer (use clang, add -stdlib=libc++ to the options and deselect "demangle symbols" in the menu). There is no indication anywhere that the function is supposed to return any specific type.
So why does gcc detect this error then?
That's because sometimes gcc does include the return type in the name mangling, and your program just happens to hit that special case. It has to do with the big great ABI breakage of C++11. gcc and libstdc++ had to change the layout of some standard library classes, notably std::string (also std::list but hey who uses that?) So the gcc authors did a clever thing to maintain backwards compatibility: they changed the mangling of everything that involves these classes --- and this time in the return type too. This way, old ABI code cannot link with new ABI code without errors. The names won't match.
You can confirm that by invoking nm on objects compiled with g++ or going to the compiler explorer again. You will see that an object than mentions void f2() still has something like _Z2f2v in it, but an object that mentions string f2() has something like _Z2f2B5cxx11v (note cxx11 in the name -- this way we know we are dealing with the new post-C++11 ABI). All is well, but if you use both functions in the same program (in different translation units), the compiler won't detect it, which is the other kind of undetectable ODR violation (still allowed by the standard).
This does not happen with other types, so if you change f2 to return say std::vector<char>, you will not get a linker error with either compiler.


Any references to cppreference or spec that allows this would be appreciated.

The program ha undefined behavior as you've odr-used f2 but haven't provided any definition for void f2(); version.  Basically, we are required to provide one and only one definition of a non-inline function that is odr-used.
This can be seen from ODR:

One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.

As you can see, the implementation is not required to issue a diagnostic for this.

In the demo shared, in main.cpp if I modify the forward declaration to string f2();, it still gives a linker error: https://godbolt.org/z/TxcKPYb54. Regardless,  g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 does give a linker error which gets fixed if I modify the forward declaration to have the correct return type. So, does look like an issue with my version of apple clang. Not sure if it's fixed in newer versions of apple clang.

@ps_ If you change the void f2() to string f2() in main.cpp it starts working. See modified demo where we don't get any linker error. There must be some problem with godbolt settings.

@ps_ See the updated answer where I've added a reference to cppreference that explains that this is undefined behavior as you must provide one and only one definition of non-inline function that is odr-used. The violation leads to UB and the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

It is not a bug. The behaviour is undefined, so anything can happen. Calling the "wrong" finction falls into the realm of "anything". Your godbolt example fails because libstdc++ treats std::string specially. Change string to vector<char> and see what happens, or use libc++ and see what happens.

Thins kind of ODR violations is ill-formed NDR I think?

@HolyBlackCat it is indeed.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Yup, when I updated the answer to say that it is UB(or IFNDR), I forgot to remove the "it is a bug" part from the answer.
